# Blank white page - laravel5 upload to server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

I have uploaded the `Laravel-5` project to server inside `demo` `folder` but when I visited `mydomain.com/demo` I got nothing i.e. blank page. I cannot actually find what is happening, I think it is because of `.htaccess` file or something else.

My folder structure inside `demo folder` is like below:

[image]

My `.htaccess`  file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My `index.php` file is like below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/CMS/bootstrap/autoload.php';



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/CMS/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

when i view error_log file i found these at last line

```
[22-Sep-2015 09:48:07 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/axilcrea/public_html/demo/CMS/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/axilcrea/public_html/demo/CMS/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

My `debug` is set true inside `app` file. I need help.

Comment: when i run php artisan serve in (/var/www/html/siddhartha/CMS) localhost i got error

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/siddhartha/CMS/app/http/helpers/backend/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/siddhartha/CMS/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 54

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5 is not supposed to work on shared hosting. Also this is really **IMPORTANT** **Laravel 5 uses php 5.5.9** that is not available on shared hostings.

You need to setup the permissions for the folders storage and bootstrap
- go to file manager in your cpanel right click on the folders and select 777 permissions and when apply make sure to check the box that all included files to get the same permissions. 
as for composer update or install and php artisan you need to make a php script to run the commands in bash. This is the workaround for shared hosting but it may not work all the times.
Or if you have shell access then you can do the composer install/ php artisan and change permissions from that shell.

Comment: on right click to demo folder i found change permission ,i made 777 and visited mydomain.com/demo but still got blank page

Comment: Do you understand that you have to go to shell in that folder and run composer install/update and artisan commands?

Comment: In your laravel folder make a new php file and add the following code 
`<?php
$output = shell_exec('composer install');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>` 
Then run in shell exec composer update and php artisan. Also for composer to work you may need to download it and you need to run other commands with this shell exec to get the composer and run php composer.phar install/update

Comment: i should make it in app directory or outside app dir

Comment: in laravel folder where you have the app storage and so on folders

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90348/discussion-between-alexander-nicholas-popa-and-ranjit-karki).

Comment: Click the continue this discussion in chat

Comment: error_log file has error:
[22-Sep-2015 13:07:29 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/axilcrea/public_html/demo/CMS/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/axilcrea/public_html/demo/CMS/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `demo` folder, make a new folder, `CMS` in the case. Move all the `contents` of your project inside the `CMS` folder except the contents of `public` directory, Then, `copy` all the contents of `public` directory in the level of `CMS` directory. Your folder structure will then look something like.

```
demo
  CMS
    app
    bootstrap
    config
    database
    resources
    storage
    and so on....
  assets
  robots.txt
  index.php
```

and your `index.php`

```
require __DIR__.'/CMS/bootstrap/autoload.php';
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/CMS/bootstrap/app.php';
```

one more thing, after completing these setup, run
`php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear`
There is really no need to do changes in `.htaccess` and also give `777` permission to `storage` folder. I always use this setup for my `laravel` project. It should work in your case too.

Comment: my structure is same as you mention above  CMS->app,bootstrap,config,resources etc

Comment: how can i give 777 permission to storage folder in server,through c- panel,is it possible?

Comment: yes its possible.. there must be some options like `change permission` when you do right click on that folder. P.S check whether you are using right `php` version or not

Comment: on right click to demo folder i found change permission ,i made 777 and visited mydomain.com/demo but still got blank page

Comment: which `php` version are you using.. it must be greater than `5.5`

Comment: it's not good to have 777 on your storage, use 755 instread, using 777 means you give everyone permission to write to it